# Adding values from a dataframe-A A.column1 by matching values in A.column2 to the B.column1 name of another dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df) A and B. df A has a column called 'Symbol' with non-unique stock-ticker-symbols as values in random order and the corresponding amount of buy or sell quantities in another column called 'Shares'; it is indexed by non-negative integers. df B, indexed by dates in the same date-order as df A and same number of rows as df A, has the same ticker symbols as df A as unique column names. I need to populate all df B rows with the amount of stock purchase or sell amounts from corresponding `A.Shares.values`. I get an error when trying the below code. Alternatively, would it be possible to loop through the df A rows using `join` command constraint to match df A's column values to column names of df B similar to SQL queries?

`import pandas as pd`

`bCN = B.dtypes.index # list of column names in df B to be used for populating its stock quantity based on matching values from df A`

`A = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2011-01-14', '2011-01-19', '2011-01-19'], 
                   'Symbol': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'IBM'], 'Order':['BUY','SELL','BUY'],'Shares':[1500, 1500, 4000]}) #example of A`

`B = pd.DataFrame({'AAPL':[0,0,0],'IBM': [0,0,0], index = pd.date_range(start, end)}) #example of B`

Expected Result

`B = pd.DataFrame({'AAPL':[1500,0,-1500],'IBM': [0,0,400], index = pd.date_range(start, end)}) #example of resultant B`

Attempt

```
    B = A.pivot('Date','Symbol','Shares')
    B = B.fillna(value = 0)
    B['Cash'] = pd.Series([0]*len(B.index),index=B.index)
    for index, row in A.iterrows():    
        if row['Order'] == 'SELL':
            B.loc[row, A['Symbol']] *= -1
```

Comment: show us A and B

Comment: Please see attached image of A and B `head` from console

Comment: did you try pivot? `A.pivot('Date','Symbol','Shares')`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I highly suggest you to read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

I think you could use pivot such has:

```
B = A.pivot('Date','Symbol','Shares')
```

Since image of dataframe are hard to copy paste I can't show you the exact result you could get using this method

Comment: Thank you for the link to the question-formatting-guidance page.